# Image Transport Compressed issue for Depth Image - ROS Fuerte

Tags: camera, ros-fuerte, image-raw, depth-image, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using **Depth Image** for one of my applications, where I need to use compressed image transport for some server/client app.
If I use param -> **"_image_transport:=raw"**, everything works fine, but if I use **"compressed"** instead of "raw", then the depth values that I get are not similar.

I am using **"/camera/depth/image_raw"** topic and converting the image into **"16UC1"** format using cv_bridge. Then I access the depth values using a Mat and type **"ushort"**.

Is there some issue with the format of image that I need to change for accessing the depth values for compressed image transport?

Thanks in advance!
Sourav

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63311/image-transport-compressed-issue-for-depth-image---ros-fuerte/) by [Sourav](https://answers.ros.org/users/3134/sourav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solution: The default compression algorithm is "jpeg" which should be changed to "png" in case of depth image.
This can be done by changing the "format" parameter for that topic(/image_transport_type).

---

Originally posted by [Sourav](https://answers.ros.org/users/3134/sourav/) with karma: 16 on 2013-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0